# In LinkedIn API v2.0, how to get company/list by person's token

Tags: linkedin-api

In LinkedIn API v2.0, how to get company/list by person's token，the api of v1.0 is v1/companies:(id,name,logo-url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As described in the [LinkedIn Company Pages v1 to v2 API Migration Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/company-pages-migration#overview)
, in the section [List companies where member has a role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/company-pages-migration#list-companies-where-member-has-a-role), you can use the endpoint with the projection using the schema definition described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/company-pages-migration#schema) fro the mapping, as example:

```
curl -i -X GET \
   -H "Authorization:Bearer <TOKEN>" \
 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityAcls?q=roleAssignee&role=ADMINISTRATOR&projection=(elements*(organizationalTarget~(localizedName,vanityName,logoV2)))'
```

Hope this help

Comment: thanks, It prompt "Not enough permissions to access", How can I apply the permission.

Comment: Hi @刘同彬 for any problems related the access permission please refer to the [migration's doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/company-pages-migration#permission-changes)  in order to handle the correct permission's migrations

Comment: I have applied for "LinkedIn Marketing Developer", how long do I wait for the reply? I have waited for about 1 week.

Comment: @刘同彬 did you end up getting approved? How long did it take and what key points did you make while applying?

Comment: @UriahsVictor, no, I have waited for more than almost one month. LinkedIn's team said they would answer me in 90 business days.

Comment: @刘同彬 just so we're on same page...you're trying to get the w_organization_social permission added to your LinkedIn app so that users connecting through it can share to/manage their LinkedIn company pages?

Comment: @UriahsVictor yes.

Comment: @刘同彬 This is the same thing we're trying to do but it seems so difficult at this point to get  this permission, have you heard success stories? I'm hoping you get through, please let me know if you do and how long it took. I'll also keep this thread in mind to let you know if we got it as well, we're applying soon.

Comment: @刘同彬 we got the permissions after around 1 month from sending the initial application.